# MS-Access Report Query Filtered by Textbox

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Report with multiple sub-reports on it.
I need to run a query for each of the sub-reports that needs to be filtered for that specific sub-report.

```
Main Report
 ____________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                            |
|    ________________________________________________________________        |
|   | Sub-Report 1                                                   |       |
|   |    _________________________________________________________   |       |
|   |   |Comment from GetCommentQuery filtered for Sub-Report 1   |  |       |
|   |   |_________________________________________________________|  |       |
|   |                                                                |       |
|   |    _________________________________________________________   |       |
|   |   |Sub Report 1 Details                                     |  |       | 
|   |   |_________________________________________________________|  |       |
|   |                                                                |       |
|   |________________________________________________________________|       |
|                                                                            |
|                                                                            |
|                                                                            |
|    ________________________________________________________________        |
|   | Sub-Report 2                                                   |       |
|   |    _________________________________________________________   |       |
|   |   |Comment from GetCommentQuery filtered for Sub-Report 2   |  |       |
|   |   |_________________________________________________________|  |       |
|   |                                                                |       |
|   |    _________________________________________________________   |       |
|   |   |Sub Report 2 Details                                     |  |       |
|   |   |_________________________________________________________|  |       |
|   |                                                                |       |
|   |________________________________________________________________|       |
|                                                                            |
|____________________________________________________________________________|
```

Comment: Why do subreports have same data source? You want each to have different filter criteria? This appears to be a design not programming issue. At least, there is no code provided for analysis. Question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Each report has its own data source.  The comment data is in a separate table. The comment refers to the sub-report.  Sub report 1 has its own comment, sub report 2 has a different comment

Comment: Then why do they all reference same query name: "GetCommentQuery"? How many subreports? Do you have a form with unbound controls for selection of filter criteria, one for each subreport? Instead of multiple subreports, this might be accomplished with one report using Sorting & Grouping.